# Dialogflow Slack integration app_mention not working

Tags: slack, slack-api, dialogflow-es

I was successfully able to integrate Dialogflow chatbot as an APP in Slack and it is accessible to chat using the APP tab.

However, for it to respond to messages in channels by mentioning like `@bot hello`
I realized that I have to add the **app_mention** event into **Subscribe to Bot Events** form.

That should work according to the documentation but it didn't in this case. so I started to wonder if that ***event*** isn't compatible with Dialogflow or if there was something missing in the documentation.

[image: SlackAPI Subscribe to Bot Events]

Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: You achieve the "same result" in dialogflow by unchecking the "Process all messages" checkbox in the slack integration, that way the bot only replies when its handle is used, or in DM

Comment: @michael_bitard Works perfect. Thanks. This should be the answer.

Comment: @Siva it does not answer exactly the question (feels more like a trick), so I felt a comment was more appropriate

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The `app_mention` event is not supported by Dialogflow.**

I reached out to both Slack's and Dialogflow's customer service after experiencing the same issues as you.

Slack checked on their side and even took a look at the logs for my bot user and saw that everything seemed to be sent to Dialogflow just fine.

Dialogflow on the other hand answered this:

> At this time, the Slack integration of Dialogflow is ideal only for
>   direct message. Bot will respond to any messages with or without a
>   mention.
>
> Unfortunately, we can’t disclose details about our releases until
>   they’re live. We announce all new features in our Change Log:
>   https://dialogflow.com/support/change-log. Stay tuned!

I just hope they'll add support for this some time soon. It's annoying not to have that feature, because now the bot user will either interfere with everything in a channel or only support direct messages. **It might help the more people take the time to contact Dialogflow support at https://console.dialogflow.com/api-client/#/support .**

Answer (score 4):

`app_mention` is now supported by dialogflow. All you need to do is subscribe to the following bot events - `app_mention` and `message.group` in Slack. And in dialogflow, under slack integration, uncheck `Process all messages` check box.

Comment: This worked for me but I subscribed to the events 1.  app_mention and 2. message.channels  when I didn't include message.channels it didn't look like events were getting sent to Dialgoflow. So it seems like app_mention might be a filter that gets applied to the other events.